# change image upon selection, searching list for the src value jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

Can anyone see anything that is wrong with this code it just isn't working...

Should be clear what I am trying to do

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#product-variants-option-0').change(function() {

     // What is the sku of the current variant selection.
     var select_value = $(this).find(':selected').val();

            if (select_value == "Kelly Green") {
             var keyword = "kly";
            };

    var new_src = $('#preload img[src*="kly"]');

        $('div.image').attr('src', new_src);

   });
 });
```

The selection:

```
<select class="single-option-selector-0" id="product-variants-option-0">
<option value="Kelly Green">Kelly Green</option>
<option value="Navy">Navy</option>
<option value="Olive">Olive</option>
<option value="Cocoa">Cocoa</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to search an unordered list:

```
<ul id="preload" style="display:none;">
<li>0z-kelly-green-medium.jpg</li>
<li>0z-olive-medium.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the html for the `form` (or just the `select` element) as well, please?

Comment: thanks; I've revised my answer. If you could explain what you're trying to achieve with the line `var new_src = $('#preload img[src*="kly"]');` I'll try to be more helpful =)

Comment: I have a list of images in a hidden ul, i'm trying to search the SRC of them images for the string "kly" and return the src as var new_src.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery find value then replace SRC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508323/jquery-find-value-then-replace-src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is this line:

```
var new_src = $('#preload img[src*="kly"]');
```

This assigns an *element* to the variable `new_src`, rather than a string; which means that when you try to change the `src` in the following line:

```
$('div.image').attr('src', new_src);
```

You're effectively inserting a dom node into an attribute, which is unlikely to work.

Try:

```
var new_src = $('#preload img[src*="kly"]').attr('src');
```

Assuming that `$('#preload img[src*="kly"]')` returns a valid `img` element, any way; from what I can see of your posted `ul` it contains text strings (but that could be the Mark-down editor at work).

---

**Edited** in response to further comments.

Has it occurred to you that *no* image exists in the `#preload` `ul` that contains the string 'kly'? This is, probably, the main problem you're having. I've copied the list over to [JS Fiddle, for demo purposes](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/evP5z/) and this version seems to work:

```
$('select').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == 'kelly green') {
            var keyword = 'kelly';
        }
        else {
            var keyword = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        }
        $('#alert').text($('#preload img[src*='+keyword+']').attr('src'))
    });
```

It could certainly be prettified, but it does work (at least given the information I've got so far).

Comment: it doesn't give me any errors, just doesn't do anything it won't alert out the new_src variable?... http://bit.ly/eLYUjU ...I'm trying to make the selector change the main image based on the option selected, I want it to search the preloader ul and copy the src to the main image.