# jQuery find value then replace SRC

Tags: jquery, replace

Can anyone see anything that is wrong with this code it just isn't working...

I am tring to:

get the value of #product-variants-option-0

search #preload for the relevant image and

then change div.image img src to that image

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#product-variants-option-0').change(function() {

     // What is the sku of the current variant selection.
     var select_value = $(this).find(':selected').val();

            if (select_value == "Kelly Green") {
             var keyword = "kly";
            };

        var new_src = $('#preload img[src*=keyword]');

        $('div.image img').attr('src', new_src);

   });
 });
```

The selection:

```
<select class="single-option-selector-0" id="product-variants-option-0">
<option value="Kelly Green">Kelly Green</option>
<option value="Navy">Navy</option>
<option value="Olive">Olive</option>
<option value="Cocoa">Cocoa</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to search an unordered list:

```
<ul id="preload" style="display:none;">
<li><img src="0z-kelly-green-medium.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="0z-olive-medium.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

The image I'm trying to replace is this:

Comment: Hm. [Exact duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504824/change-image-upon-selection-searching-list-for-the-src-value-jquery/4504852).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1. You're not converting "Kelly Green" to "kelly".
2. The `var new_src = $('#preload img[src*=keyword]');` has `keyword` hardcoded into it (not the value of the keyword variable).
3. <s>The `li`s in the list don't have `img` elements inside them (they just directly contain the URL as text).</s> *You've edited the question and fixed that.*
4. If the select value isn't "Kelly Green" you're not making it lower case, and you're not using the value at all.
5. You're not retrieving the `src` attribute of the preload image.

<s>If you change the list to:</s>

```
<ul id="preload" style="display:none;">
<li><img src='0z-kelly-green-medium.jpg'></li>
<li><img src='0z-olive-medium.jpg'></li>
</ul>
```

*(That was part of what was fixed.)*

Then this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#product-variants-option-0').change(function() {
     var select_value, keyword, new_src;

     // What is the sku of the current variant selection
     select_value = $(this).find(':selected').val();

     // Get the keyword to use (the value in lower case, or "kelly" if the
     // value is "Kelly Green")
     keyword = select_value == "Kelly Green" ? "kelly" : select_value.toLowerCase();    

     // Find the image using that `src`, note that we concatenate the value
     // from `keyword`, rather than having it in a literal.
     new_src = $('#preload img[src*=' + keyword + ']').attr('src');

     // Set the image's source.
     $('div.image img').attr('src', new_src);
   });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/owiyi4)

---

Charles, you asked for input on how it might be written differently, and I said I had a minute to do something up. Sorry for the delay, my Real Job needed me for a moment.

I'd probably approach it like this, with the assumption that you have this kind of select box elsewhere in your application and therefore generalization is worthwhile.

1. Make things reusable wherever possible (well, almost; there's one bit of generalization I left as an exercise to the reader).
2. Don't store the image URLs in one place and the options in another; put them together, so they can both come from the same data source easily. This reduces error. (For instance, in your question, you have four options, but you only have images for two of them in the preload structure. Now, if you don't have images for the others, that's fine, leave the attribute off or make it blank, but keeping things together / generated from the same source is a good idea.)
3. Do #2 with the `data-image` attribute, which is valid as of HTML5 and perfectly harmless in earlier versions. ([Details](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/))
4. Don't include the markup for the preloading in the HTML; generate it. This relates to #2, and also to the fact that users who don't have JavaScript don't need the precached images as they won't be used. So don't push them things they don't need.

HTML:

```
<select class="single-option-selector-0" id="product-variants-option-0">
<option
  value="Kelly Green"
  data-image="0z-kelly-green-medium.jpg"
  >Kelly Green</option>
<option
  value="Navy"
  data-image="0z-navy-medium.jpg"
  >Navy</option>
<option
  value="Olive"
  data-image="0z-olive-medium.jpg"
  >Olive</option>
<option
  value="Cocoa"
  data-image="0z-cocoa-medium.jpg"
  >Cocoa</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<div class='image'><img src='placeholder.jpg'></div>
```

JavaScript with jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  // A utility function from my arsenal; you can
  // just inline this if you don't want it.
  // Returns an array containing the given attribute
  // from *all* of the elements in the jQuery object.
  // Args:
  //  name        Name of the attribute to fetch
  //  blanksOkay  (Optional, default false) true if
  //              you want blanks in the array for
  //              blank entries or non-existant entries;
  //              false if you want them left out.
  $.fn.attrAll = function(name, blanksOkay) {
    var list, index;

    if (typeof blanksOkay === "undefined") {
      blanksOkay = false;
    }

    list = [];
    for (index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
      entry = $(this[index]).attr(name);
      if (entry || blanksOkay) {
        list.push(entry);
      }
    }
    return list;
  };

})(jQuery);

// The page's ready script
jQuery(function($) {

  // Set up the product variants select box.
  // You could generalize this with classes or other attributes
  // (so there would be *nothing* special about the select box),
  // but I didn't want to change your markup too much.
  setupSelectWithImages(
    '#product-variants-option-0',
    'div.image img:first'
  );

  // ===
  // All of the following would probably be in your
  // utility script; it's not page-specific.
  // ===

  // Set up our select box that's equipped with images
  // so it shows the image when an option is selected.
  // The options within the box should have data-image
  // attributes for their images, which are precached.
  // Args:
  //   boxSelector     The selector that finds the select box
  //   targetSelector  The selector that finds the target img
  function setupSelectWithImages(boxSelector, targetSelector) {
    var box;

    // Get the select box
    box = $(boxSelector);

    // Preload the images
    preloadImages(box.find('option'), 'data-image');

    // Ensure we show the correct image when the select box
    // changes, and force showing it right now for the default
    // value.
    setCurrentImage.call(box[0]);
    box.change(setCurrentImage);
    function setCurrentImage() {
      var entry = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-image');
      if (entry) {
        display("Setting src to " + entry);
        $(targetSelector).attr('src', entry);
      }
    }

    // Done with box
    box = undefined;
  }

  // Another general purpose function; preloads the images
  // defined by the given attribute on the elements in the
  // given jQuery object.
  // I've kept things bundled up (in a div rather than a ul),
  // but there's no special reason to, you could just add
  // the individual images to the body directly.
  // Using a container makes it easy to return a single
  // thing out of this function, which may be useful
  // to some calling code.
  function preloadImages(list, attrName) {
    var markup;

    // Get a list of the relevant attribute
    markup = list.attrAll('data-image');

    // Convert it into a bunch of img tags
    markup = joinEntries(markup, "<img src='", "'>");

    // Put them in an off-page div, add it to the document,
    // and return the div to the caller
    return $("<div/>").css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': '-10000px',
      'top': '0px'
    }).html(markup).appendTo(document.body);
  }

  // Join the entries in the array with the given
  // prefix and suffix.
  function joinEntries(a, prefix, suffix) {
    prefix = prefix || '';
    suffix = suffix || '';
    return prefix + a.join(suffix + prefix) + suffix;
  }

  // This is just for our purposes in this demo
  function display(msg) {
    $("<p/>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/owiyi4/2) (but the live example uses some gravatars, so you can actually see the images)

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code... should be better now, but still not working

Comment: @Charles: The update still has the same problem, just with different text ("keyword" instead of "kly").

Comment: Thanks very much, look at that much cleaner I see where I was going wrong! Think we had crossed posts

Comment: THIS WILL NEVER WORK! `keyword` is `kly`, and there is no `kly` in any of filenames. It is also an awful practice to rely on filename containing a keyword. What if other filename also contains it in an unpredictable place? **update** I did not read the answer correctly. However, it still implies to use a bad practice - the same one that poster used.

Comment: @Michael: Er, -1 seems a bit harsh for just the filename thing, but whatever. The OP is in control of the filenames, it's up to him to control them. He asked why what he was doing didn't work, and I told him why and showed him how to fix it. I didn't rearchitect it.

Comment: Your right this isn't working correctly I'm get [object][object] as the div.image img src.

Comment: @Charles: I missed something. It's now #5 on the list, code fixed.

Comment: I'm happy with all the comments anything to help me get it right!

Comment: @TJ thanks for that, quite confussed with all this not as straight forward as I thought would you suggest re-thinking it?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: [object][object] issue was also missed initially. Honestly, I would just completely rewrite the code, if I saw such in my project. It is really bad, so if a guy asks what is wrong, I not only make it work, but also make it follow good practices.

Comment: @Charles: I have a minute, let me show you how I'd do it. One sec.

Comment: @Michael: Whatever. The criterion is: Is it helpful? I think it was. In any case, SHOUTING is generally inappropriate, and it's best to comment before downvoting to give people an opportunity to correct what you've seen, This is a professional forum for helping one another.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: true, I removed downvote, sorry. Still I believe that helping means correcting all the issues that can be found, not only making something bad a bit worse, as it seems to be good, yet being bad.

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, got busy there doing something else; added rearchitected example. Still a bit off-the-cuff but you see where I'm going.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#preload img[src*=keyword]');` will not find anything, there is no `img` inside `#preload`. You should define `id` for every `li`, and these ids will equal you keywords. After that you can do `$('#preload #' + keyword).text()` - this will return correct `new_src` value

**UPDATE**
After your edit: do not put images inside `li`s! This will needlessly increase traffic! Put just sources:

```
 <li id="kly">pathto.jpg</li>
```

Comment: *"After your edit: do not put images inside lis! This will needlessly increase traffic! Put just sources"* The whole point of that `li` structure is to preload the images. That's why it has the name "preload".